# TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager +UpdateOrderOption with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project that involves using a datasource (access 2013 database) and showing it in details form with binding navigator control.I am using VS 2013 but have chosen .NET Framework 4.0 as my Target framework during creation of the project.Now, i have added the DB through "Add New DataSource" Wizard and dragged the table(details view and not gridview) to the form.When I run, i am getting the following error :

***Code Generation for property 'UpdateOrder' failed. Error Was: 'Type'Action.Action2DataSet TableAdapters.TableAdapterManager +UpdateOrderOption' is not available in the target framework.'***

Also in the output window, i am getting this:
*A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll*
*The program '[23260] Wk4DB.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'*

but the same works with .NET 4.5 as target.But the project has to be run with VS 2010 and I have VS2013 installed in my machine.My question is, if i do the project with Framework 4.5, will it run on VS2010 in other machines?Please help.
Thanks!